# Mac Docker Machine ZSH shell set env variable not applying

Tags: macos, shell, docker, zsh, docker-machine

I am running Docker Machine on Mac.

```
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
```

In my shell I have done

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker.local:2375
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0
```

Restarted the machine

When I do

```
docker-machine env
```

These do not seem to have been set. I am using the ZSH shell, could this be an issue?

```
docker-machine env 
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1" 
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"   
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/ciaran/.docker/machine/machines/default" 
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `docker-machine env` it will show the variables that are needed in order to connect to the `default` machine. It has nothing to do with the variables in the current shell, and will not set any variables in your shell.

To see the current docker variables in your shell, you can run

```
$ env | grep DOCKER
```

If you want to set your shell ENV variables to the ones in `docker-machine env`, you will need to either copy and paste the output of `docker-machine env`, or eval the output like this.

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env <machine name>)
```

That will set the variables in your shell. This command is actually given to you when you run `docker-machine env` look at the end of the output.

To confirm it worked, check the shell again.

```
$ env | grep DOCKER
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes that woks but how do I set a docker machines env variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by docker machines env variable. Do you mean an ENV variable for the linux host that docker is running on?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity but yes that is what I mean.
I want to change DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY for a docker machine.

Comment: docker-machine currently doesn't allow you to do that. But if you ssh into the machine you should be able to do it manually `docker-machine ssh <machine name>` and then edit `/etc/default/docker` to set your variables and then restart docker.